# atlas search: How to index UUID field and query by UUID

Tags: mongodb-atlas, mongodb-atlas-search

I have mapped UUID column(_id is UUID in mongo) to string and set the anylyzer to keyword like this in atlas search index mapping

```
          "_id": {
            "analyzer": "lucene.keyword",
            "type": "string"
          },
```

and when I am querying _id, that's not working.

```
"text": {
  "path": "_id",
  "query": "568ae8be-168d-4675-a442-fe93836e1b50"
}
```

So not sure how UUID mapping should be set up and searched in altas search

Comment: Did you try to specify "path": "_id" (with underscore)?

Comment: Yes my bad, it was editing mistake have corrected now

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported yet according to

https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/atlas-search-compound-index-uuid-text/142813

https://feedback.mongodb.com/forums/924868-atlas-search/suggestions/41287666-add-support-for-uuid-datatypes-in-atlas-search?_ga=2.54212203.255378698.1643462300-46448687.1607590524&_gac=1.216671778.1643266205.EAIaIQobChMI186v1KvR9QIVkA4rCh3fLwzVEAAYASABEgJtrfD_BwE

Comment: Any workaround?